# The index of $\xi_4^*$ in $\xi_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Just seeing if i'm right:

With the set of solutions for $z^4=1$: $\xi_4=\{1,i,-1,-i\}$, one can construct the group of the $4$th roots of unity: $(\xi_4,\cdot_\mathbb{C})$ and its multiplicative subgroup $(\xi_4^*,\cdot_\mathbb{C})$ with $\xi_4^*=\{1,-1\}$.

> What is the Index $[ \xi_4 : \xi_4^* ]$?

I'd say through Lagrange:
$$ [ \xi_4 : \xi_4^* ] =\frac{|\xi_4|}{|\xi_4^*|}=\frac{4}{2}=2.$$
Or counting the cosets of $\xi_4^*$: 
$$1\cdot\xi_4^*=\{1,-1\}= -1\cdot\xi_4^*,\quad i\cdot\xi_4^*=\{i,-i\}= -i\cdot\xi_4^*$$
we get two.

Is this correct?

Comment: What does $\xi_4$ mean?

Comment: So $\xi_4$ is $4$th roots of unity, and $\xi_4^*$ is the square roots of unity?

Comment: sorry, I missed to clarify that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, indeed, the index $$[\xi_4:\xi^*_4] = \frac{|\xi_4|}{|\xi^*_4|} = \dfrac 4 2 = 2$$

Alternatively, as you've shown, the *index* $=$ *the number of cosets* of $\;\xi^*_4 \leq \xi_4 = 2$.

**REMARK:**
When you're dealing with a finite group, as in this case, the first "method" of computing the index of a subgroup with respect to its containing group is probably quickest. (Indeed, the first method works strictly for finite groups!)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks good.  There are $2$ cosets of the subgroup $\xi_4^*$ in $\xi_4$.